# Install ffmpeg/ffprobe on localhost for laravel 4 package?

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg, ffprobe

How can I install ffmpeg and ffprobe on my localhost, so that I can use sonus ffmpeg laravel-4 package? 
https://github.com/rafasamp/sonus

Can I just get it directly from git?

```
git clone git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing *git clone* would get the FFmpeg Source Code, you need to compile it to have a local version running in localhost. Easiest way is to get one of the precompiled version for your Operating System at [FFmpeg download section](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) and then configure the fully qualified system path in sonus config.php:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ffmpeg System Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to know the fully qualified system path to where ffmpeg
| lives on this server. If you paste this path into your shell or
| command prompt you should get output from ffmpeg.
|
| Examples:
| Windows: 'C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe'
| Mac OSX: '/Applications/MAMP/ffmpeg/ffmpeg'
| Linux: '/usr/bin/ffmpeg'
|
*/

'ffmpeg'    => '/usr/bin/ffmpeg', //for GNU/Linux
```